# An exercise on Dini derivatives

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

[image]

**(a)** : The other three definitions are in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative).

**(b)** : $D^+f=0$, $D_-f=0$, $D_+f=-\infty$ and $D^-f=\infty$.

**(c)** : ?

**(d)** : By considering $h=\frac{1}{n}$, $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of measurable functions are measurable?

I cannot find a solution for **(c)** ; and am I correct about **(b)** and **(d)**?

Comment: Functions of bounded variation can be expressed as differenced of monotone increasing functions. Monotone increasing functions are differentiable Lebesgue-almost-surely (Although the result of Lebesgue almost surely differentiability of monotone functions is "surely" discussed in your textbook, here is a [link](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m448s18/LebesgueTheoremMonotoneFunctions.pdf) that may be of interest to you). As for (d), you can always take $h\rightarrow0$ through rationals.

Comment: (c) seems correct: $f=\mathbb{1}_Q$. If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$
$$D^-f(x)=\limsup_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{1-f(x-h)}{h}=\infty$$
$$D^+f(x)=\limsup_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(x+h)-1}{h}=0$$
$$D_-f(x)=\liminf_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{1-f(x-h)}{h}=0$$
$$D_+f(x)=\liminf_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(x+h)-1}{h}=-\infty$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz, (c) is a question is about Dini derivatives not just derivatives and the book says : "Let f be of bounded variation on [a, b].Thenf has a finite 
derivative almost everywhere." How can this be generalized for Dini derivatives?

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point $x$ (in the usual sense), what do you think happens to the Dini derivatives? Now, since a function of finite variation is differentiable at almost every point, what the values of the Dini derivatives should be?

Comment: @OliverDiaz, all 4 of them coincide, I believe. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It not only a believe, it is actually easy to prove. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, $$\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(x_0)\Big|<\varepsilon$$. Thus, for $0<|h|<\delta$ $$f'(x_0)-\varepsilon<\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}<f'(x_0)-\varepsilon$$ The conclusion should be easy from this.